# Parse a dynamic json objects from a json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, parsing

I have this dynamic json object

```
{
   "servers":[
      {
         "comp1":{
            "server1":{
               "status":"boxup",
               "ar":{
                  "0":"95.61"
               },
               "ip":{
                  "0":"192.168.1.0"
               }
            },
            "server2":{
               "status":"boxup",
               "ar":{
                  "0":"99.5"
               },
               "ip":{
                  "0":"192.168.0.1"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "comp2":{
            "server1":{
               "status":"boxup",
               "ar":{
                  "0":"88.39"
               },
               "ip":{
                  "0":"198.168.1.1"
               }
            },
            "server2":{
               "status":"boxup",
               "ar":{
                  "0":"99.88"
               },
               "ip":{
                  "0":"192.168.0.1"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "comp3":{
            "server1":{
               "status":"none",
               "ar":"none",
               "ip":"none"
            },
            "server2":{
               "status":"boxup",
               "ar":{
                  "0":"99.97"
               },
               "ip":{
                  "0":"http:\/\/122.01.125.107"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "comp4":{
            "server1":{
               "status":"boxup",
               "ar":{
                  "0":"95.64"
               },
               "ip":{
                  "0":"192.168.1.0"
               }
            },
            "server2":{
               "status":"boxup",
               "ar":{
                  "0":"95.65"
               },
               "ip":{
                  "0":"192.168.1.2"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "comp5":{
            "server1":{
               "status":"boxup",
               "ar":{
                  "0":"71.92"
               },
               "ip":{
                  "0":"192.168.1.0"
               }
            },
            "server2":{
               "status":"boxup",
               "ar":{
                  "0":"98.89"
               },
               "ip":{
                  "0":"192.168.0.3"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and I tried to parse it with $.each (refer below)

```
$.ajax({
        url:"/server-monitoring/load-servers",
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(e){
            if(e.success){
                $.each(e.servers,function(index,value){
                    //log the status from server1 on every comp
                    console.log(value.server1.status);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

but unfortunately and sadly, it returns me an error (refer below)

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

any help, ideas, suggestions, recommendation, clues please?

Comment: you are trying to loop a json. json is a string. you need to parse it to a object and then loop it

Comment: And why are you doing `e.success`? are you trying to check if the ajax call was a success?? or the message from the server has a success in it?

Comment: Because each object in the array has a primary key called `comp[num]` which is an object and within that is the server object which contains the status property.

Comment: @Reddy, jQuery auto-parses the JSON if the `dataType` has been set correctly. You don't need to parse it again.

Comment: @Andy . thanks for the info,

Comment: problem is `console.log(value.server1.status);`  The value is the current instance of the object array. Let take the first object. It doesn't have server1 in it.. it has to be `comp1.server1`

Comment: @Reddy: yes, please assume I have "success = true" in the back end json response.

Comment: @Reddy: yes I can do that but the problem is object array is dynamic, e.g. its not always comp1, comp2 etc.. so I cant parse it that way. any ideas?

Comment: Now the question got tougher.. lemme try my stuff

Comment: the only dynamic is they key object e.g. comp1, comp2, and etc. and the rest is static inside the json response. I just want to retrieve that dynamic object key name e.g. comp1, comp2 and etc..

Answer (score 2):

From your structure of response, following will work

```
$.each(e.servers,function(index,value){
                    //log the status from server1 on every comp
                    console.log(value['comp'+(index+1)].server1.status);
                });
```

Gives output as

```
boxup
boxup
none
boxup
boxup
```

**Edit:**

After clarification in comment and assuming there will be any single key
Below can work

```
$.each(e.servers,function(index,value){
                    //log the status from server1 on every comp
                    var key = Object.keys(value)[0];
                    console.log(value[key].server1.status);
                });
```

Comment: Nice @Andy +1,
Reddy's comment in that direction..Cool!!

Comment: actually there's a circumstances where its not comp1, comp2 and etc.. so I cant parse it like console.log(value['comp'+(index+1)].server1.status); because the comp is dynamic e.g. it can be "adelle" and not comp

Comment: Is there will be single key?

Comment: ahahah thats what even I am wondering.. I think its multiple.. and his server1 can also be multiple.

Comment: guys, the only dynamic is they key object e.g. comp1, comp2, and etc. and the rest is static inside the json response.

Answer (score 1):

How about this code. It will handle dynamic keys, number of objects and dynamic inner objects too.

```
$.each(data.servers, function(key, value) {
   $.each(this,function(key,value){
       var parentObj = key;      
       $.each(value,function(key,value){
          console.log(parentObj + '------'+key + '-----'+value.status);       
       });
   });
});
```

Here is a [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/Lcw89b1o/1/)

And here is the output.

```
comp1------server1-----boxup
comp1------server2-----boxup
comp2------server1-----boxup
comp2------server2-----boxup
comp3------server1-----none
comp3------server2-----boxup
comp4------server1-----boxup
comp4------server2-----boxup
comp5------server1-----boxup
comp5------server2-----boxup
```

Answer (score 0):

By Observing your JSON structure, I believe that each server object (in servers array) has one property like comp1, comp2 ... which is not known.

Following code works.

```
   var comp = {}; //Just a temp variable to hold dynamic comp property
                  // value

   $.each(v.servers,function(i,v){ 
      //Loop through each key in server object to find first property.
      for(var key in v) {
        //Make sure its objects own property, just to be safe.
        if(v.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // Fetch our comp (assumed, you can also match key 
            // and make sure it starts with comp ...
            comp = v[key];
            break;
        }
      }
      //As we have our comp object, now we can access server1, server2 as shown below
      console.log(comp.server1.status);
    });
```

Hope this helps !! Let me know if you need further assistance .... :)